# Eclipselink Integrity Checker

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

I'm using EclipseLink and I'd like to check whether entity and table definitions are consistent.

I found "Integrity Checker" and tried it.

```
public final class EMF {

    public static class EnableIntegrityChecker implements SessionCustomizer {

        @Override
        public void customize(Session session) throws Exception {
            session.getIntegrityChecker().checkDatabase();
            session.getIntegrityChecker().setShouldCatchExceptions(false);
        }
    }

    private static final EntityManagerFactory INSTANCE;
    static {
        String appId = SystemProperty.applicationId.get();
        Map<String, String> overWriteParam = new HashMap<>();

        overWriteParam.put(
            PersistenceUnitProperties.SESSION_CUSTOMIZER,
            EnableIntegrityChecker.class.getName());

        INSTANCE = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("unit", overWriteParam);
    }

    private EMF() {
    }

    public static EntityManager create() {
        return INSTANCE.createEntityManager();
    }
}
```

Some cases it can detect inconsistency, but some cases can not.

1. If entity has variable A and table does not have column A, Integrity Checker can found inconsistency.
2. If table has colume A and entity does not have variable A, Integrity Checker can **not** found inconsistency.
3. If column A in table is int and variable A in entity is String, Integrity Checker can **not** found inconsistency.

How can I detect inconsistency in case 2 and 3?

Answer (score 0):

You can extend `IntegrityChecker`, override it's `checkTable` method and use it via `session.setIntegrityChecker(customIntegrityChecker)`. Note that some of validations are located in `ClassDecriptor#checkDatabase` so it's hard to directly re-use them and properly report exact error cause.